# filter object by two nested values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, filtering

I'm facing a problem with filter method. On my page there's an input to search matches by team names. Filter value is being stored to React state. Matches object looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "teamBlue": {
            "id": 36,
            "name": "nameForTeamBlue",
            "playerList": [
                {
                    [...]
                }
            ]
        },
        "teamRed": {
            "id": 37,
            "name": "nameForTeamRed",
            "playerList": [
                {
                    [...]
                }
            ]
        },
        "localDate": "2020-01-01",
        "localTime": "00:00:00",
        "referee": null,
        "commentator1": null,
        "commentator2": null,
        "streamer": null,
        "stage": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "GROUPSTAGE"
        },
        "onLive": true,
        "finished": false
    },
]
```

I tried tons of methods to filter matches by team name, for example:

```
      let criteria = {
        teamBlue: {
          name: this.state.filter
        },
        teamRed: {
          name: this.state.filter
        }
      };
      let filteredMatches = this.state.matches.filter(function(item) {
        for (let key in criteria) {
          if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] !== criteria[key])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
      console.log(filteredMatches);
```

but none of them worked.
Is there any way to filter these matches so when I type "blue" into my input, it will show all matches where team name contains "blue"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only filter by name or if criteria has key `id` then you want to filter by id as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the condition to:

`if (!item[key] || item[key].name !== criteria[key].name)`

```js
let filteredMatches = this.state.matches.filter(function(item) {
    let flag = true;

    for (let key in criteria) {

      // update this to
      if (!item[key] || item[key].name !== criteria[key].name)
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
  });
```

Comment: Ok, could you check you conditions inside `if`? and also update the json object and input (I don't see any `blue` in the json object)

Comment: `let criteria = {
        teamBlue: {
          name: this.state.filter
        }
      };
`
also for teamBlue there is `"name": "nameForTeamBlue"` so it contains "blue"

Comment: @SajibKhan at the moment `criteria[key]` is `{
          name: this.state.filter
        },` so you're comparing objects that always return false.

Comment: Try this condition: if (!item[key] || item[key].name !== criteria[key].name)

Comment: @Apraxia if `name` property was assumed all along then why even nest it in criteria, you could simplify with `criteria = {
        teamBlue: this.state.filter...`

Answer (score 0):

The name property is missing :

```
if (key in item && item[key].name !== criteria[key].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing objects with === which will return false. You either need to use a deep comparison method from a library, or implement it yourself like below:

```js
const matches = [ {"id": 4,
    "teamBlue": {
        "id": 36,
        "name": "nameForTeamBlue",
        "playerList": []
    },
    "teamRed": {
        "id": 37,
        "name": "nameForTeamRed",
        "playerList": []
    },
}, {"id": 4,
    "teamBlue": {
        "id": 36,
        "name": "nameForTeamBlue",
        "playerList": []
    },
    "teamRed": {
        "id": 37,
        "name": "nameForTeamRead",
        "playerList": []
    },
}]

const criteria = {
  teamBlue: {
    name: 'nameForTeamBlue',
  },
  teamRed: {
    name: 'nameForTeamRed',
  }
}

const filteredMatches = matches.filter((item) => {
  const allCriteriaMatched = Object.entries(criteria)
    .every(([key, value]) => {
      const matched = Object.entries(value).every(([criteriaKey, criteriaValue]) => {
        const itemValue = item[key][criteriaKey]
        const matched = itemValue == criteriaValue
        if (!matched) console.log('Item %s does not matched criteria %s. Item\'s value is %s, but criteria value is %s', item[key]['id'], criteriaKey, itemValue, criteriaValue, criteriaValue)
        return matched
      })
      if (!matched) return false
      return true
    }, {})
  return allCriteriaMatched
})
console.log(filteredMatches);
```

Basically, you just need to go 1 level deeper :D if your criteria can have multiple nested objects, then there's no point doing it manually. You can try to map criteria to run against matches so that you don't use `===` on objects, but only primitives.